# google maps api v3 multiple markers infowindow onclick works but not when called outside

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a weird problem and maybe I am just not seeing it clearly.  It definitely always helps to have others look at my code.  Anyways, I have a drop down menu with options in it, needless to say, onchange it calls a function to open an infowindow.  The listener for the click works perfectly fine when displaying the info window, but the handleSelected() function does not display anything.:

```
<select size='37' id='dpMenu' onchange='handleSelected(this)'>
```

Now I have an array for my markers outside of my function that creates the markers.

```
var gmarkers = [];
var oldInfoWin; 
var map;    

function createEpiMarker(map,point,epi_icon,html,name,detail,iqrid) {    
    var epimarker = new google.maps.Marker({    
        position: point,  
        map: map,  
        icon: epi_icon  
    });  
    epimarker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html });  
    google.maps.event.addListener(epimarker, "click", function() {   
        epimarker.infowindow.open(map, epimarker);  
        oldInfoWin = epimarker.infowindow;  
        infoWindowOpen = true;  
    });  
    gmarkers.push(epimarker);  
}
```

This code here handles the dropdown menu selection:

```
function handleSelected(opt){    
    var i = opt[opt.selectedIndex].index - 1;   
    if(i != -1){        
        gmarkers[i].infowindow.open(map, gmarkers[i]);        
        oldInfoWin = gmarkers[i].infowindow;    
        infoWindowOpen = true;    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just triggering a click on the marker to display the "working" infowindow?

Comment: the provided code doesn't encompass the issue, please post more code or a demo.

Comment: as mentioned by @geocodezip just trigger click event on the corresponding marker...like this..
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], 'click');

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I posted the question at the end of work and when I got home, well...its the weekend...but yes! The trigger click works, I didn't do that previously because I did not know of it, I am not too familiar with javascript, just learning as I go...thanks a bunch for the help!